# Sorting Objects Within Mongo Document [Python]

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I have this MongoDB Atlas Document:

[image: Atlas Doc]

```py
a = {
    '_id': 'FBRT',
    'releases': {
        '07-29-2022 07:00:00': {
            'type': 'news'
        },
        '07-26-2021 00:00:00': {
            'type': 'exchange',
            'file': 'pdf'
        },
        '06-01-2022 06:30:00': {
            'type': 'article'
        },
        '06-16-2022 16:30:00': {
            'type': 'news',
            'live': True
        },
        '05-04-2022 17:31:00': {
            'type': 'news',
            'file': 'pdf'
        },
        '10-19-2021 00:00:00': {
            'type': 'brief',
            'format': 'html'
        },
        '06-29-2022 06:30:00': {
            'type': 'press',
            'file': 'pdf'
        }
    }
}
```

How can I sort the objects within `releases` (by the date keys) with PyMongo? I find the document and object, but then what? Do I have to parse as datetime first?

Comment: Would you edit your question and paste the entire document in a codeblock (or at least the complete `releases` object and some indication of the other fields, etc., present in the document)?  What you are looking for is definitely possible, but without the entire document it's difficult to supply a correct/complete solution.

Comment: I didn't believe the omitted fields were relevant, but here you go!

Comment: Using any data as a field name is considered to be an anti-pattern in MongoDB.  From personal experience, I can write that using any data as field names only leads to future query pain.  You are experiencing a little of that pain now.

Comment: Soooo no ideas? I've used Atlas extensively for the last several months and only came to this standstill now.

Comment: You really want to continue with this data model?  Only seeing what's here, I'd much rather have `"releases"` as an array and the objects something like `{"datetime": ...}`.

Comment: The additions I made were just some random keywords and tags, there's quite a lot more data there. My issue with your structure is the annoying inconvenience of having to open an extra drop-down when viewing documents visually via web and the inability to see all dates laid out all at once in this situation - I'll keep searching!

Comment: Using your data model, it's still possible, just more complicated.  Are you looking for an aggregation pipeline to return the sorted `"releases"`?  Should it have the same structure?  Or are you looking to update the database/collection/document with the sorted `"releases"`?  Or are you looking to sort `"releases"` in python?

Comment: I am indeed attempting to sort and replace the document with the same structure after inserting more data.